# Selecting nested navigation properties will generate the same SQL statement when selecting separate navigation properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following repository method:-

```
public AccountDefinition GetCustomer2(int id)
        {      var c = entities.AccountDefinitions.Where(p => p.ORG_ID == id)
               .Include(a => a.SDOrganization)
               .Include(a2 => a2.SiteDefinitions)
                .Include(a3 => a3.SDOrganization.AaaPostalAddresses)
                .Include(a4 => a4.SiteDefinitions.Select(a5 => a5.DepartmentDefinitions.Select(a6 => a6.SDUsers.Select(a7 => a7.AaaUser.AaaContactInfoes)))).SingleOrDefault();
return c; }
```

But when I comment some code I found that the generated SQL statement when calling the Action method will be the same:-

```
public AccountDefinition GetCustomer2(int id)
        {      var c = entities.AccountDefinitions.Where(p => p.ORG_ID == id)
           //    .Include(a => a.SDOrganization)
            //   .Include(a2 => a2.SiteDefinitions)
                .Include(a3 => a3.SDOrganization.AaaPostalAddresses)
                .Include(a4 => a4.SiteDefinitions.Select(a5 => a5.DepartmentDefinitions.Select(a6 => a6.SDUsers.Select(a7 => a7.AaaUser.AaaContactInfoes)))).SingleOrDefault();
return c; }
```

So does this mean when I navigate to a nested  Navigation property , then EF will automatically retrieve parent navigation properties also? . so for example when i write `.Include(a3 => a3.SDOrganization.AaaPostalAddresses)` , then there is no need to write `.Include(a => a.SDOrganization)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell yes, it has to otherwise there is no way for you to traverse to that navigation property

EG, the only way to access `AccountDefinition.SDOrganization.AaaPostalAddresses` is if `SDOrganization` is not null.

Having said that my personal preference is to make this intermediate inclusion explicit by listing it anyway. While this has no functional benefit its a reminder that this property will also be returned

Comment: But will the entity framework in this case send two queries to the database; one to get the "AccountDefinition.SDOrganization.AaaPostalAddresses" , while the other to get the "AccountDefinition.SDOrganization".???

Comment: @johng No this will be executed in a single join

Comment: But what control this , i mean what will force EF to construct one single join not multiple queries ?